# Retrieve Arraylist from Shared Preferences

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I am working on `shared Preferences`. Basically, I am saving `ArrayList` to `shared preferences` which are working fine. Now I want to retrieve the `ArrayList` from `Shared preferences` but I am getting null. ArrayList is retrieving from preferences and also showing it's size. but data is not being set to string. How I retrieve the ArrayList from shared Preferences.
here is my code

```
public void saveRootCategory(List<Category> categories){
    preferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("RootCategory",categories.size());
    for (int i=0;i<categories.size();i++){
        setData(categories.get(i));
    }
    editor.apply();
}
public void setData(final Category category){
    categoryId = category.getId();
    categoryName = category.getCategoryName();
    editor.putInt("CategoryId",categoryId);
    editor.putString("CategoryName",categoryName);
}
public  ArrayList<String> getRootCategoy() {
    preferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    ArrayList<String> rootCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    rootCategories.clear();
    int size = preferences.getInt("RootCategory", 0);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        int Id = preferences.getInt("CategoryId" + i,0);
        String name = preferences.getString("CategoryName" + i ,"");
        rootCategories.add(String.valueOf(Id));
        rootCategories.add(name);
    }
    return rootCategories;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same null problem
Here's how I solved it
I have an arrayList named `language`

```
language = new ArrayList<String>
```

I had to add everything the user writes on the edittext on button click not repeating any redundant value

```
    if(!language.contains(value)) {
         language.add(value);
}
```

To save this arraylist I created a `hashSet`

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

and save all of them `onPause`

```
set.addAll(language);
.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
.commit();
```

and retrive it back to `language` array list `onCreate`

```
prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit=prefs.edit();
set = prefs.getStringSet("yourKey", null);
            language = new ArrayList<String>(set);
            edit.remove("yourKey").commit();
```

remember to remove everytime or it will again create null

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the index in `setData`. Change it to

```
public void setData(final Category category, int index){
    categoryId = category.getId();
    categoryName = category.getCategoryName();
    editor.putInt("CategoryId" + index, categoryId);
    editor.putString("CategoryName" + index, categoryName);
}
```

Comment: what is index please explain it

Comment: @ansarabbas You try to get the name by calling `getString("CategoryName" + i)` but you save it without `i`. The index is your `i`.

Comment: but how i save list with index?

Comment: @ansarabbas Did you even try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to save the `ArrayList` into the `share preference`.

I Suggest you can use **[PaperDB](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper) Library**.

Which is very fast and directly save your `ArrayList` same as `preference` doing.

You can also use it to store the Primitive datatypes and model class directly.

Note: It also reduces the code lines.

Answer (score 0):

Add some breakpoints on `setData()` -> `editor.putInt("CategoryId",categoryId);` and debug your code are necessary.

BTW, it seems that there's no difference you call either `editor.apply()` or `editor.commit()` running on API 9 or above devices.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your both methods with these:

```
public void saveRootCategory(List<Category> categories){
    preferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("RootCategory",new Gson().toJson(categories));
    editor.apply();
}

public  ArrayList<Category> getRootCategoy() {
    preferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String data = preferences.getString("RootCategory","");
    return new Gson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<List<Category>>(){}.getType());
}
```

No third party library needed use Gson(inbuilt) library which can easily do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`public void setData(final Category category)`
The method use the same key("CategoryId", "CategoryName") to save every item in the list. 
However, you use `"CategoryId" + index` to get the value from SharedPreference.
Obviously, you can never get the right answer in this way...

@Murat's answer correct the method, and it can work well.
But I don't think it's a good way to save a List. If you do want to use SP to save Lists, I suggest `Gson` or any other way to translate your object into `String` first. It will work better.